# deploy adonisJs fullstack on vercel

Tags: vercel, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

I would like to deploy adonisjs fulltack application on vercel, but always get 404 message.

Adonisjs documentation : https://adonisjs.com/

[image]

**I try to change :**

- the build script by overflowing the build script by  : node ace --production && cp .env build/.env
- and overflow package management tool by npm istead of yarn

I try to add vercel.json file :

```
{
"version": 2,
"buildCommand": "node ace build --production",
"devCommand": "npm run dev",
"installCommand": "npm install",
"outputDirectory": "build",
"public": true,
"env" : {
"PORT":"3333",
"HOST":"127.0.0.1",
"EMAIL_SENDER_NAME":"",
"montravaux_BASE_URL":"http://localhost:3333",
"NODE_ENV":"testing",
"APP_KEY":"",
"DRIVE_DISK":"local",
"SESSION_DRIVER":"cookie",
"HASH_DRIVER":"bcrypt",
"CACHE_VIEWS":"",
"DB_CONNECTION":"",
"PG_HOST":"d",
"PG_PORT":"",
"PG_USER":"",
"PG_PASSWORD":"",
"PG_DB_NAME":""
},
"routes": [
{
"src": "/(.\*)",
"dest": "/start/route.js"
}
]
}
```